# Hiding labels for CanvasJS chart?

Tags: javascript, ajax, canvas, pie-chart, canvasjs

I have a Canvas JS chart and if the values are 0, I'd like to hide the labels. 2 of my datapoints are non-zero. My JavaScript is:

```
           var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
            {
                title:{
                    text: ""
                },
                legend: {
                    maxWidth: 350,
                    itemWidth: 120
                },
                data: [
                {
                    type: "pie",
                    showInLegend: true,
                    toolTipContent: "${y} - #percent %",
                    dataPoints: [
                        { y: debt, indexLabel: "Debt Payments" },
                        { y: housing, indexLabel: "Housing" },
                        { y: utilities, indexLabel: "Utilities" },
                        { y: foodandsupplies, indexLabel: "Food and Supplies"},
                        { y: transportation, indexLabel: "Transportation" },
                        { y: health, indexLabel: "Health"},
                        { y: otherDebts, indexLabel: "Other payments"}
                    ]
                }
                ]
            });
            chart.render();
```

The outcome of the JavaScript is:

[Pie Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FOPy.png)

I would appreciate any help with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the indexLabels for dataPoints with zero as y values by going through the chart options and setting the indexLabel as empty string for all such dataPoints.

Add this code snippet before rendering the chart i.e. `chart.render()` and it should work fine.

```
for(var i = 0; i < chart.options.data[0].dataPoints.length; i++) {
 if(chart.options.data[0].dataPoints[i].y === 0)
  chart.options.data[0].dataPoints[i].indexLabel = "";
}
```

Hope it helps.